# Why does related function work while using relationships doesn't in PowerPivot?

Tags: powerpivot

If I create a pivottable using fields from two different datasets (that are related), the system churns and eventually errors out with a message about not enough system resources. If I add a field to one of the tables using the "related" function, and then only use fields from the one table in the pivottable, everything works fine.

Clearly, I don't understand relationships in PowerPivot, as I would think the two things would be equivalent. Can someone help give me a better understanding of why one works and the other doesn't, when it seems they should be doing the same thing?

More specific example:

Import two odata feeds, customers and orders, set up relationship, and then create pivottable using fields from both: does NOT work.

Import two odata feeds, customers and orders, set up relationship, and then add a field to the orders table that uses the "related" function to get the customername from the customers table, then build a pivot table using only fields from the orders table (including the "related" field):  This works fine.

Comment: How large is your dataset?

Comment: A few hundred rows in one table, and less than ten thousand in the other.

Comment: Is there any way you could provide me with some sample data?

Comment: I'm actually using Project Online. Unfortunately, Microsoft doesn't have a sample environment (I think), and I don't have a test Excel file to post anywhere at the moment. So, there's actually 3-5 tables for each "report": projects, tasks, assignments, resources, etc. Each table uses a guid for the IDs.

Comment: could you possible draw a schema of the tables and highlight the relationships? It might be tricky to do some calculations as there are limitations how the data can travel across tables (and it gets even more when filters/context rows are introduced).